# Java FX Bindings: bind a dynamic list of boolean properties

Tags: java, javafx, javabeans

I'm trying to create a `BooleanProperty` for my `CustomPane`, let's call it `isEmpty`.

This property should be **true** when a collection (filled at runtime) of `TextField` objects matches a condition. *This list does not change its content once given.*

In this case the condition is that all fields must be empty (no text in any of the fields).

So when the `CustomPane` object is constructed, I have the list of fields and I should bind all their `.textProperty().isEmpty()` toghether.

Any suggetions on how I could do this?

Comment: So you want a variable that will tell you if everything is empty? If that’s all then I can write the code out for you when I’m home but basically it would be just grabbing each text box by id and then if all of them return true with .isEmpty() then setting your Boolean to true.

Comment: @DragonHeart000 not exactly, the variable is a property so it should update on its own.

Comment: So kinda like what I said but just have it check if it's still true every time an action is taken by the user?

Comment: A live property allows for the implementation of a listener that fires when the property changes. A manual check every time however..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
private BooleanBinding areTheyEmptyBinding(List<TextField> list){   
    BooleanBinding bind = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false).not();
    for (TextField text: list)
        bind = bind.and(text.textProperty().isEmpty());
    return bind;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I cannot (I don't know how) give the inital empty value.
= new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);  is a compilation error.

Comment: I meant something different, the error I get is:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleBooleanProperty to BooleanBinding

Comment: @LoryA aah ok! it should be fixed now.